# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not getset_descriptor

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, syntax-error, typeerror

I am trying to code a script that finds out the current date and time and then creates a folder with a name based on this. 
I get this error when I try to run my code:

> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not getset_descriptor

This is my code:

```
import os
import time
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime
initYear = "%04d" % (d.year) 
initMonth = "%02d" % (d.month) 
initDate = "%02d" % (d.day)
initHour = "%02d" % (d.hour)
initMins = "%02d" % (d.minute)ion where you wish to save files. Set to HOME as default.
# If you run a local web server on Apache you could set this to /var/www/ to make them
# accessible via web browser.
folderToSave = "/home/timelapse/timelapse_" + str(initYear) + str(initMonth) + str(initDate) +        str(initHour) + str(initMins)
#os.mkdir(folderToSave)
# Set the initial serial for saved images to 1
fileSerial = 1
a = 'timefile'

# Run a WHILE Loop of infinity
while True:
     if os.path.isfile(a) == False:
    # Set FileSerialNumber to 000X using four digits
    fileSerialNumber = "%04d" % (fileSerial)
    # Capture the CURRENT time (not start time as set above) to insert into each capture image filename
    hour = "%02d" % (d.hour)
    mins = "%02d" % (d.minute)
    # Define the size of the image you wish to capture.
    imgWidth = 800 # Max = 2592
    imgHeight = 600 # Max = 1944
    print " ====================================== Saving file at " + hour + ":" + mins
    # Capture the image using raspistill. Set to capture with added sharpening, auto white balance and average metering mode
    # Change these settings where you see fit and to suit the conditions you are using the camera in
    os.system("raspistill -w " + str(imgWidth) + " -h " + str(imgHeight) + " -o " + str(folderToSave) + "/" + str(fileSerialNumber) + "_" + str(hour) + str(mins) +  ".jpg  -sh 40 -awb auto -mm average -v")
    # Increment the fileSerial
    fileSerial += 1
    # Wait 10 minutes before next capture
    time.sleep(600)
else:
    os.remove(time.txt)
os.system("sudo shutdown -h -P now")
break
print "Quitting now."
sys.exit(0)
```

I think the code has an error here:

```
initYear = "%04d"
```

The error seems to be around the "%04d" part. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you putting *into* this format string? The placeholder specifications are *not the problem*.

Comment: That's not where your error is.  Please provide the traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did remove "% (d.year)" from the end of the "%04d" bit in the hope that it would work but it didn't help.

Comment: @Gerrat Here's the traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 28, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not getset_descriptor

Comment: @TomD: `d.year` is a descriptor, because `d` is a reference to the `datetime` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a `datetime` instance here:

```
d = datetime
```

That is just a new *reference* to the `datetime` type. The attributes `d.year`, `d.month`, etc. are *descriptors* there, not values you can interpolate:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.year
<attribute 'year' of 'datetime.date' objects>
>>> type(datetime.year)
<type 'getset_descriptor'>
>>> '%04d' % datetime.year
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not getset_descriptor
```

If you wanted to current timestamp, you'll need to call `datetime.now()`:

```
d = datetime.now()
```

There are better ways to use the datetime value in a string. You could use the [`datetime.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to produce a string format for your date:

```
formatted = d.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
folderToSave = "/home/timelapse/timelapse_" + formatted
```

or you can use the same formatting codes in a `str.format()` interpolation:

```
folderToSave = "/home/timelapse/timelapse_{:%Y%m%d%H%M}".format(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue is your use of datetime.  datetime is a class, not a method.

to get the current date, use:

```
d = datetime.now()
```

It looks like you are trying to format the various date components.
To reference them, however, you need to use this sort of format:

```
inityear = str(d.year)
```